# Need to install new video card, what kind?

Tags: graphics-card

I have a Lenovo H430 desktop that has an integrated graphics card. I want to add an additional graphics card and I read the motherboard specs from which I found I have `3 PCIE x1 slots` and `1 PCIE x16 slot`.

I searched and found there are both x1 and x16 graphics cards. Which one to buy? Also, there are PCIE x16 2.1 and 3.0. What is the difference and how do I figure if which one goes in my system?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, x1 cards are meant for servers, and niche applications - I'd avoid them unless, well, I had to use a x1 slot.

Between 2.1 and 3.0, most video cards, even the high end ones should work fine with 2.1 - 3.0 provides roughly twice the bandwidth, and is future proof - considering that crossfire or SLI often involves running cards at x8, x16 of either variety provides sufficient data ba. In this case though, with what looks like a modern system, I'd look at the graphics card's other specs and use case rather than which version of PCIe it supports. PCIe is forwards and backwards compatible anyhow.